# Spring Cloud Kafka Binding with Synchronous Rest Call

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm working on a micro service powered by SpringMVC and Spring Cloud Kafka.

For simplicity I will only focus on the part that makes HTTP request.

I have a binding function like the following (please note that I'm using the functional style binding).

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleApplication {

  // PayloadSender uses RestTemplate to send HTTP request.
  @Autowired
  private PayloadSender payloadSender;

  @Bean
  public Function<KStream<String, Input>, KStream<String, Output>> process() {

    // payloadSender.send() is a blocking call which sends payload using RestTemplate,
    // once response is received it will collect all info and create "Output" object
    return input -> input
      .map((k,v) -> KeyValue.pair(k, payloadSender.send(v))); // "send" is a blocking call

    // Question: if autoCommitOffset is set to true, would offset automatically commit right after the "map" function from KStream?
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ExampleApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

From this example you can see that the payloadSender is sending the payload from the input stream using RestTemplate and upon receiving the response creating the "Output" object and produce to the output topic.

Since payloadSender.send() is blocking, I'm worried that this will cause performance issue. Most importantly if the HTTP request gets timed out, I'm afraid it will exceed the commit interval (usually the HTTP timeout interval is much much greater than the consumer commit interval) and cause the kafka broker to think the consumer is dead (please correct me if I'm wrong).

So is there a better solution for this case? I would eventually switch over to spring-reactive but for the time being I need to make sure the MVC model works. Although I'm not sure spring-reactive would have magically solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `max.poll.interval` is 5 minutes; you can increase it or reduce `max.poll.records`. You can also set a timeout on the rest call.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Is increasing the poll interval the only option here?

Comment: Yes, or set a timeout on the rest call; if you suspend the thread for longer than that, the broker will consider the consumer to be dead.

Comment: Right that's what I'm afraid of, I definitely don't want the broker to think the consumer is dead. I guess I will have to set the poll interval longer than timeout?

Comment: You need to be sure that ALL records retrieved by the poll are processed within the `max.poll.interval`. You can set `max.poll.records` to determine how many records (at most) will be returned by the poll.

Comment: Thanks for the help!